# Delphi 10.2 SOAP WSDL Import - XML Mailformed

Tags: xml, delphi, soap, wsdl

There is a very simple SOAP Interface for a ERP System. I have tried to talk to that System by importing the WSDL file via delphi WSDL Importer. Everything works properly as expected.

Port is present, Interface is present, HTTPRIO object get's added with BasicAuth, everything is fine. unfortunately, when I send Data to the Service the Server is not able to process the Data. Than I was trying with SOAP-UI with the same WSDL file for that Service. Everythin works fine. So I use Wireshar to sniff the difference between that Network traffic and think I found the Problem. First here are the XML Files from that 2 Systems. First SOAP-UI which works:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:ZxftSamWsRecCrea>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ImCustomerId>
                007
                </ImCustomerId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ImSearchVal>
                MASCHINE
                </ImSearchVal>
            <ImVkc>
                0815
                </ImVkc>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ImVkcDescr>
                Test VKC
                </ImVkcDescr>
            </urn:ZxftSamWsRecCrea>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And here comes the XML File created by Delphi:

```
<?xml
    version="1.0"
    ?>
      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ZxftSamWsRecCrea
            xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <ImCustomerId
                xmlns="">007
                </ImCustomerId>
            <ImSearchVal
                xmlns="">MASCHINE
                </ImSearchVal>
            <ImVkc
                xmlns="">0815
                </ImVkc>
            <ImVkcDescr
                xmlns="">Test VKC
                </ImVkcDescr>
            </ZxftSamWsRecCrea>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

3 Questions in my mind for that:

1. Do I need that XML Version Information, or could it be removed. And
   how can I Achieve that?
2. How can I get rid of that Empty Namespaces?
3. Isn't the Namespace for "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" at the wrong node? How could that be corrected or is it not important?

Comment: Apart from the missing `Header` element, the documents look equivalent to me. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I only get Timeouts. But that is a fault from the ServerSide. I get a Timeout even when using SOAP UI. But with SOAP-UI the Data Appears in the ERP System.

Comment: Strange. The first thing to do would be to investigate that timeout.

Comment: Thats a Thing I can not do, that mast be done by the ERP Software Team. It is definitly a Thing that should be done before the Interface runs productive but at that Moment my only goal is to change my Delphi code in a way that it looks like the one who is working.

Comment: As @Olivier says, the only significant difference is the absence of the Header element. It's possible that the server is getting upset about differences that shouldn't be significant, but rather than tweaking that, I would concentrate on (a) getting better diagnostics as to why the document is rejected, and (b) fixing the missing Header. (I don't know Delphi, but if I did, I would be saying that if you want advice on how to change your Delphi code, it would be a good idea to show us that code.)

Comment: @MichaelKay I think you get me Wrong. By the Missing header you mean the "<?xml version="1.0"?>"? That is the Output Delphi is creating, which does NOT Work.

Comment: No, I meant the empty `<soapenv:Header/>` element. The XML declaration is fine (it's in an unusual but perfectly legal format) and any XML parser will accept it. (Omitting the `<soapenv:Header/>` element is also fine, according to the SOAP specification.) I think the real problem here is that you don't know what the problem is, and you're trying to fix it by trial and error. You need some diagnostics.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you to point that out, I was missing the Fact that there is an Empty Header. Even Stranger that this XML is working. I will try to get more diagnostic Information. I am in Contact with the ERP Software developer now.